# Connection between error probability and MSE

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, asymptotics, information-theory

**Setup:** Given that we have an estimate $\hat{\beta}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ of a signal $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We have the error probability $P_e=\mathbb{P}[\hat{\beta}\neq\beta]$ and the mean squared error (MSE) $\frac{1}{p}\|\beta-\hat{\beta}\|_2^2$.

**Question:** Given that we have $\text{MSE}\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, can we show that $P_e\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$? This seems intuitive to me but I can't seem to show it rigorously. I was thinking we can show this by deriving some upper bound
$$
P_e\leq C\cdot \text{MSE},
$$
where $C$ is some constant (non growing as $n\rightarrow\infty$). Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is obviously $P_e\equiv 1$

Comment: You mean to say $P_e=0$?

Comment: No, i mean $P_e\equiv 1$... Also there are many typos in your post; if they really are correct, then i think it needs some clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this isn't possible in general. Consider $\beta=0$ and $\hat \beta =1/n$. In this case, MSE goes to 0, but $P_e$ is 1 for all $n$